# I need a potentiometer controlled by only a 0-10v signal

Tags: pwm

I have a PWM control box made for standard 4 pin PC type fans (12v).  It has a potentiometer to control the fan speed via PWM.  It is powered by its own 12v supply.  I would like to exchange this manual potentiometer with one that is controlled by a 0-10V signal.  The 0-10v signal is coming from an aquarium controller and is intended to adjust an LED driver.  I can program this aquarium controller to vary the voltage based on sensor inputs.  Ideally adjusting fan speed based on temp/humidity/pH sensors via the 0-10v output.

My biggest concern is not damaging the expensive aquarium controller (source of 0-10v). I obviously need to crack open the PWM fan controller and measure the potentiometer.

I'm having difficulty figuring out what I need to use or search for.  A digital potentiometer seems close, but needs more inputs than I can provide.

Fan PWM:
https://noctua.at/en/na-fc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most interesting way might be to use one of the Atmel ATTiny chips (ATTiny 13A would do it) or an Arduino. Divide the 0-10v by a convenient amount (2 or 3), read it in to the ADC and generate a PWM signal proportional to the input voltage.

If you want to do it the easy way, then [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06VVVGGBN) seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: Good point, a PWM controller is not hard to make from scratch, no need to try to understand someone else's one.

Comment: That easy way is I think exactly what I need for a perfect solution.  I can convert the 0-10v analog signal to PWM from the board you linked and send it to My Noctua PWM module for the fan. The Noctua unit will treat it like a PWM signal from a MOBO and run at that speed.  While still allowing me to use the potentiometer to attenuate the speed and also utilize the anti-stall function.  Thanks BobT, I would have not found that board without your help!